# Extracting indrect relation in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, sequence

I have this table

```
ID  S   E
1   a   b
1   b   c
2   a   b
2   b   d
2   b   e
2   e   d
3   a   c
3   c   f
```

I want to extract indirect relations from this table for example:

```
ID  S   E
1   a   c
2   a   d
2   a   e
2   b   d
3   a   f
```

I could do it in C# or Java but I am wondering if there is a solution for doing it in SQL or not.

Comment: Only one hop away, or transitively ?

Comment: Many thanks for your comment Joop. Transitively is better. for example a=>b, b=>c and c=>d be in the first table, If I could have a=>d would be greate!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Answer: Yes, there is a solution. Hint: recursive CTE. (the recursive keyword is optional at Microsoft)

Comment: Thanks for your response and your hint. Finally, I could do it using your trick and Bihavika answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this...

```
Create table #a (ID int, S varchar(1), E varchar(1))

Insert into #a
select 1, 'a', 'b' Union all
select 1, 'b', 'c' Union all
select 2, 'a', 'b' Union all
select 2, 'b', 'd'Union all 
select 2, 'b', 'e'Union all 
select 2, 'e', 'd'Union all
select 3, 'a', 'c'Union all
select 3, 'c', 'f'


select * from #a

select a.S, b.E 
from #a a 
     Inner join #a b on a.E = b.S and a.ID = b.Id 

drop table #a
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, is there any way to have more indirect relations!  for example, a=>b, b=>c and c=>d be in the first table, having a=>d. I know another inner join could find it. But in this way, I should have several times inner join and I also don't know how many inner join should I have.